# conditional expression, its syntax and evaluation

Tags: syntax, scheme, conditional-statements, evaluation

Could someone clarify why does the procedure return 22? it is clear that this statement is not written correctly but anyway why does it return 22?

thank you in advance.

```
(define (proc x)    
      (cond (= x 22)     
            (display 3)     
            (display 4)    
      )
)    
(proc 3)
```

Comment: In the first cond clause, `=` is not `#f` (it is a primitive operator), so it is considered true, `#t`, and then `x` and `22` are evaluated in sequence, and the final result is `22`.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a couple of parentheses. In this code:

```
(define (proc x)
  (cond (= x 22)
        (display 3)
        (display 4)))
```

You're testing if the `=` procedure is `true` - which it is, because in Scheme everything is truthy, except `#f`, which is `false`. And given that `=` is `true`, the last value corresponding to that condition is returned, in this case: `22`. The correct syntax for `cond` is as follows:

```
(define (proc x)
  (cond ((= x 22)
         (display 3)
         (display 4))
        (else 'error)))

(proc 22)
=> 34
(proc 3)
=> 'error
```